# "Endpoint not reachable. Refresh cache and retry" Azure Cosmos DB SQL API, .NET SDK

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using .NET SDK `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` to work with cosmos db on Azure.
I've a problem when my network cannot connect to cosmos db (proxy, network, ...)

Example:

```
   this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), PrimaryKey, new ConnectionPolicy {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct, ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
            RetryOptions = new RetryOptions {MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 5, 
            MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds= 5 },
            RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(1000)});
var a = await this.client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = "FamilyDB" });
```

My application loop forever in line `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` and with message:

```
Endpoint not reachable. Refresh cache and retry
Failover happening. retryCount 6
RefreshLocationAsync() refreshing locations
An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
Endpoint not reachable. Refresh cache and retry
Failover happening. retryCount 7
RefreshLocationAsync() refreshing locations
An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
....
```

I cannot stop or try catch it, I tried `requestoption`, `requestTimeout` but it is not working.

So if I cannot connect to cosmos db, how can i stop it or try catch it.

Comment: In the 2.x version of the .NET SDK, you can pass a CancellationToken which would allow you to cancel the operation. Today, you cannot handle this remote error in the SDK itself. We've got a new version of the SDK we're working on that will let you add a handler that would customize the handling of this error.

Comment: If you send an email to AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com, you can get ahold of the engineering team. There is probably a feature we could add which would make this fail faster, even without a custom handler.

Comment: Thanks!, It's so bad :( My app is running and cannot stop, so You think I can use timeout on my code :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`OpenAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.openasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_OpenAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) on `documentClient` object to check whether
it was initialized successfully.

It will throw exceptions for `End Point not reachable` as well as `Invalid Authorization Key`

```
DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPointUri), authKey);

try
    {
        await documentClient.OpenAsync();
    }

catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle Exception Here
    }
```

You can proceed with querying on successful initialization of `DocumentClient`